Strongly Future asymptotically predictable space
Consider a spacetime $(\mathcal{M},g)$ which is a weakly asymptotically empty and simple spacetime and partial Cauchy surface, $\mathcal{P}$ in $\mathcal{M}$. $(\mathcal{M},g)$ is called strongly future asymptotically predictable from the partial Cauchy surface $\mathcal{P}$ if $\mathcal{I}^+$ is contained in the closure of $D^+(\mathcal{P})$ in $\tilde{\mathcal{M}}$ and if $J^+(\mathcal{P}) \cap J^{-}(\mathcal{I}^+)$ is contained in $D^+(\mathcal{P})$
I am having problem in few things in the above definition. First of all, why are we taking partial Cauchy surface instead of Cauchy surface ?
Secondly, What is closure of $D^+(\mathcal{P})$ ? How can we define this intuitively ? I know D represents domain of dependence here but what do we mean by "closure of domain of dependence" ?

For the first question, it is because you are only looking at the asymptotic region. In the non empty part the space time can be very complicated, it need not have a Cauchy surface. For the second it means the topological closer. The set need not be closed you may need to add points to it.
